# Can i not show the message that apears when HTA is activated

Tags: hta

I tried using an HTA to deploy some files to the users computer. I would like to do so silently cause our users get upset by the fact that they need to approve the activation of the HTA every time the enter the page.
Can i somehow disable the apearance of the message?

TIA,
Arik

Comment: @skaffman: HTA being this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application It's quite handy, if you're OK with the fact that it is an IE-only deprecated technology.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...the message is, IIRC, a security warning, is that correct?

Adding your site to the Trusted Zone might help you (this is a client-side browser (MSIE) setting).

Answer (score 0):

Unless the HTA file is residing on the user's computer, you'll just have to live with the security warning.

I, for one, certainly wouldn't want a web page running with such elevated security settings without my approval!  This is just the sort of thing virus writers would want.

Answer (score 0):

A novel solution, is you can deploy once a HTA application which can be an empty page with an `IFRAME`, i.e.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<br/>
<iframe src="http://somewhere.org" />
</body>
</html>
```

That way, the HTA application can be rerun repeatedly without the need of repeated authorization since it's already on the computer. However, the content of the HTA can be updated by update the remote document specified in the `IFRAME`.